# Customizing points in `xsim`

Tags: exsheets, xsim

The points in `exercise` environment seem to align right under the line of the exercise name and label as shown here

[image]

How do I left it upwards as follows

[image]

This alignment is the typical behavior of `exsheets`. I also want the points brackets and text to be formated as shown above.

One more thing, `exsheets` provides explicit options to customize points by using `\SetupExSheets[points]{<options>}` where `<options>` include `format`, `number-format`, `bonus-format`, `separate-bonus`, `pre-bonus`, and `post-bonus` as well as `points-pre-code` and `points-post-code` (in heading template). What are the equivalent of these in `xsim`?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=\rule{1.07\textwidth}{0.3pt}, points=5, bonus-points=1]
    Something written here
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I contrast to `exsheets` the default layout in `xsim` simply uses a `\subsection*` followed by a `\marginpar` for the points. In order to change this you will have to define your own layout template. The manual has a few examples to help you get started. Below I show another example. I also added in the rule although I guess you only had that in the question to demonstrate the vertical alignment…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{needspace,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
  \par\vspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
  \Needspace*{3\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\normalfont\large
  \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  \IfInsideSolutionF{%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
  }%
  \normalsize
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
    \marginpar{%
      (%
        \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~[+\printgoal{\PropertyValue}]}%
      )%
    }%
  }%
  \hrulefill % << delete this line if you don't want the rule
  \par\vspace{1.5ex plus .2ex}
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
{}
\makeatother

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template = custom ,
  solution/template = custom
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[points=5, bonus-points=1]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

From The example above it shouldn't be too hard to get the solution aa in the picture – assuming that the numbering follows the sectioning of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim,xcolor,needspace}
% filler text:
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}{%
  \par\vspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
  \Needspace*{3\baselineskip}%
  \noindent\normalfont\normalsize
  \textcolor{blue}{%
    \textbf{\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}\nobreakspace\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
  }%
  \IfInsideSolutionF{%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ {\normalfont\itshape\PropertyValue}}%
  }%
  \normalsize
  \GetExercisePropertyT{points}{%
    \marginpar{%
      (%
        \printgoal{\PropertyValue}%
        \GetExercisePropertyT{bonus-points}{~[+\printgoal{\PropertyValue}]}%
      )%
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{1.5ex plus .2ex}
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
}
{}
\makeatother

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/the-counter = \thesubsection.(\Alph{exercise}) ,
  exercise/template = custom ,
  exercise/name = Question ,
  solution/template = custom
}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\begin{exercise}[points=5, bonus-points=1]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[points=2, bonus-points=3]
  \lipsum[4]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]